# jquery cookie plugin or code not working in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I have this code in my page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ba_object_Code").change(function () { $("#HRBK").val($(this).val()); });
            $.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
            if (sessid == 'xyz') {
                $("#ControlPlanID").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            $(".t-grid-action.t-button.t-state-default.t-grid-add").click(function () {
                $.cookie('sessid', 'xyz');
            });

        });
```

I am getting this error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: did you include the jquery cookie plugin after including jQuery?

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that something isn't included correctly.

Comment: Two things: 1. sessid is never initialized (line 4) 2. on which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not defining sessid, so when you call it, it will fail.

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zNDHN/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var sessid = $.cookie('sessid');

            $("#ba_object_Code").change(function () { $("#HRBK").val($(this).val()); });
            $.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
            if (sessid == 'xyz') {
                $("#ControlPlanID").removeAttr('disabled');
                console.log('cookie_found');
            }
            $(".t-grid-action.t-button.t-state-default.t-grid-add").click(function () {
                $.cookie('sessid', 'xyz');
                console.log('cookie_created');
            });

        });
```

Comment: I am not sure which plugin should I use?

Comment: What do you mean? In the code you pasted, you are using jquery and jquery cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Answer (score 1):

order is important and jquery files have to be included in_layout.cshtml incase master page is used... ['JQuery' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339314/jquery-is-undefined)