# TypeError: jQuery is undefined WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on WordPress Site and it's showing this error in console, again and again. If I am running my site on local environment than it doesn't having any issue. But after uploading on server, it shows j Query  errors that

> TypeError: jQuery is undefined

And I can't load my site, because of this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/339332/916000

Answer (score 2):

Make sure jQuery library is referenced on your site.

Please add to the page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A still better way is to go to the above link and store the js in a xxx.js file and then refer to this file in the script's src property.

Comment: Yea I found the issue, jQuery is also loaded but having broken path, so I updated my db and path and it resolved all my problem.